# Sum a column if another column contains any of the values

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data in a google spread sheet.

```
ColumnA         ColumnB
=======================
Bus             205
Train           10
Train           10
Fruit           10
```

I want to sum all ColumnB where ColumnA is equal to either Bus or Train.

I know that I can sum all content of B based on single value of A like below

```
=(SUMIF(A:A, "Bus", B:B))
```

But I want to sum if column A contains any of the values that I specify. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(sumif(A:A,{"Bus";"Train"},B:B)))
```

## Explanation

- `A:A` is the column containing the categories.
- `{"Bus";"Train"}` is a 1x2 array. It could be replaced by a range 1xn arrange containing the categories to be included in the sum.
- `B:B` is the column containing the values to be summed.
- `sumif` returns of the sum of values corresponding to each specified category
- `sum` returns the sum of the returned array by `sumif`
- `ArrayFormula` :

> Enables the display of values returned from an array formula into
>   multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with
>   arrays.

## Reference

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
=sumproduct((A:A="Bus")+(A:A="Train"),B:B)
```